# Re-athenticated with the stolen cookies in Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel-sanctum

I setup a SPA authentication with Laravel Sanctum, it works fine. I login successful with an user. In Chrome Devtools, Application > Storage > Cookies, I copy and save the values of `laravel_session` and `XSRF-TOKEN` to a text file, then logout and delete all cookies and refresh browser, here I logged out.

Then I re-open Devtools, restore the values of `laravel_session` and `XSRF-TOKEN` manually, refresh browser, now my status is logged in.

Is this normal? Is this the way that cookie based session authentication work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. My problem was that I called `Auth::logout()` instead of `Auth::guard('web')->logout();` inside my **AuthController** in Laravel.

By using `Auth::guard('web')->logout();` the cookies seem to get revoked by the server and can't be used for authentication any more.

By the way, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63449251/10095327