# Laravel sanctum SPA authentication logout is not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

I am using laravel sanctum SPA authentication in my Vue project.Everything is working well but even after logout

```
Auth::logout()
```

I am still able to get datas from api route inside middleware

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

I should not be able to get datas after logout.It should show 401 unauthenticated but its not the case.
How to solve this problem.I have been stuck here for 3 days.I followed laravel documentation and other tutorial as well but every one logged out same like I did.

Comment: is `sanctum` the default guard?

Comment: Above route is written in api.php so default guard is api @lagbox

Comment: the default guard is set in the configuration `auth.php` ... when using the auth functions if you don't pass a guard in it will use the default ... if the default isn't `sanctum` then you are **potentially** calling `logout` on a different guard

Comment: Ok then you mean i should pass sanctum guard in logout?

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I have the same issue, everything works well with postman, but vue keeps me logged even if I revoke the token through postman

Answer (score 13):

Kindly use `Auth::guard('web')->logout();` instead of `Auth::logout()`. look into [SPA Log out issue](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/87)

Answer (score 0):

To Logout, a user simply do this in you logout function to delete all the user tokens

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();
}
```

Or user this to remove only the active token

```
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me now is :
`auth('sanctum')->user()->tokens()->delete();`

Answer (score -1):

In order to logout the specific user, You need to specify the user.

```
// Revoke a specific user token
Auth::user()->tokens()->where('id', $id)->delete();

// Get user who requested the logout
$user = request()->user(); //or Auth::user()
// Revoke current user token
$user->tokens()->where('id', $user->currentAccessToken()->id)->delete()
```

Comment: Cleaner way `$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();`

Comment: I am using SPA authentication not API token authentication.This answer may suit for that.anyway thanks for response.